# Decomposition of ideal $I=(x^{2}-yz,xz-x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

My teacher give us an exercise to determine if the ideal of a polynomial ring k[x,y,z](where k is an algebraically closed field) can be decomposed into smaller ideal. The ideal is $I$=($x^{2}-yz$,$xz-x$). The answer is that $I$=($y,x$)$\cap$($z,x$)$\cap$($x^{2}-y,z-1$).

I know that $I$ is the intersection of $(x^{2}-yz,x)$ and $(x^{2}-yz,z-1)$, but then I thought it cannot be further decompose. How to arrive the given answer?

Comment: I think your proposed answer should start out $(x, y)$.

Comment: You are right, I will edit that

Comment: @Ken.Wong Sorry to bother you, but i stumbled upon this question and i'm interested in the method you used to conclude that $I$ is the intersection of the ideals $\left ( x^2 - yz, x \right )$ and $\left ( x^2 - yz, z - 1 \right )$. Of course, as long as it is not a bother, just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @Hmm $xz-x=x(z-1)$. Without loss of generality, forget about $x^2-yz$, any polynomial that is divisible by $x(z-1)$ must be divisible by $x$ and $z-1$, so these polynomial must be elements of $(x)$ intersects with $(z-1)$

Comment: @Ken.Wong Right, and that would show that $I$ is included in the intersection, but what about the other inclusion?

Comment: @Hmm Both $x$ and $z-1$ are irreducible polynomial, so if the element of intersection are divisible by both of them, it is divisible by the product of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first ideal is the same as $(yz, x)$. Thinking about the corresponding geometric set of points (scheme, variety, whatever), this is $x=0$ and $yz=0$. That is, the union of two lines in the $x=0$ plane.